# spring cloud stream kafka actuator metrics not publishing to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I have a simple spring cloud stream application using kafka binder.
I have added metrics configuration for actuator, however I am not getting any metrics into metrics topic, infact metrics topic is not even getting created.

Full project here https://github.com/kothapet/SpringCloudStreamKafka1

I added the following to pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.github.kothapet</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringCloudStreamKafka1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Spring Cloud Stream Kafka1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And added these to application-local.properties (running with profile=local)

```
#
spring.application.name=SCSDemoApp
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
#
#
management.health.binders.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
#
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.applicationMetrics.destination=metrics-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.applicationMetrics.binder=kafka
#
spring.cloud.function.definition=upperController
#
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upperController-in-0.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upperController-in-0.destination=input-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upperController-in-0.group=SCSDemoApp-group1
#
#
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upperController-out-0.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.upperController-out-0.destination=output-topic
#
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
#
```

And here is the class

```
package com.github.kothapet.SpringCloudStreamKafka;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public Function<String, String> upperController() {
        return message -> {
            System.out.println("Before :" + message);
            String rval = message.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("*After : " + rval);
            return rval;
        };
    }
}
```

I get actuator health thru http://localhost:8080/actuator and actuator/health
Any thoughts on what am I missing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this feature. Where is it documented that Spring Cloud will actively produce metrics into a topic (as in, how many records per minute, for example)? How would it know what cluster to interact with? What serializer and other producer configs to use? In other words, your config here alone is not enough to produce to any Kafka topic

Comment: Here is the documentation. 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/multi/multi_spring-cloud-stream-overview-metrics-emitter.html

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.metrics.properties` defaults to null. Perhaps you need to specify producer settings here? Otherwise, where is `metrics-topic` output binding defined? As mentioned, what you've shown has no information about Kafka. Please create a [mcve] rather than link to external repo

Comment: I added full code here. As you probably know Spring assumes the binder, since there is only one binder defined in pom, anyways I added kafka as the binder.
I dont know what goes into spring.cloud.stream.metrics.properties?

Comment: I found that it works fine in spring cloud stream Version 3.x, but doesn't work on Version 4.x.

Comment: Looks like you also asked via GitHub. See my comments there and use that as a starting point. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2758#issuecomment-1599672899. The gist is that the old way of publishing metrics to a Kafka topic is now removed and you need to export metrics to a system like Prometheus, Wavefront etc. via Spring Boot Micrometer support.

Comment: @sobychacko Does the documentation typically have deprecation notices? Or should those pages be removed from 4.x docs?

Comment: The documentation mentioned above is from an older version of Spring Cloud Stream. I guess google search still finds those pages. If you go to the main project page and look at the latest documentation, those sections are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Spring Cloud stream 4.x this feature is deprecated completely. However Spring cloud stream can get kafka binder micormeter based metrics to destinations like Prometheus.
See the issue here
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2758
and also documentation here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-metrics